# How can I copy a dialogs position coordinates into another dialogs?

Tags: c, winapi, dialog, items

I have a few unique push buttons and I only want to show one of them at a time.  I want them to be centered, so I have the first push button centered on the dialog.  If I want to show the 3rd push button, I want to give it the first buttons coordinates and hide the 1st button.

How can I copy a buttons coordinates and set another buttons coordinates to the copied values?

Ex. Lets say I have...

```
PB_ONE
PB_TWO
```

How can I grab PB_ONE's coordinates and set PB_TWO's coordinates to PB_ONE?

```
RECT rcButton;

GetWindowRect(GetDlgItem(hDlg, PB_ONE), &rcButton);
```

The above code grabs the dialog item I want to copy the coordinates from.  Is there a simple command that sets another dialog button to this dialogs coordinates?

something like SetDlgItem()?

UPDATED WITH THE NEW CODE I TRIED BASED OFF THE ANSWER

```
GetWindowRect(GetDlgItem(hDlg, PB_ONE), &rcButton);
ClientToScreen(hDlg, &p);
OffsetRect(&rcButton, -p.x, -p.y);
SetWindowPos(GetDlgItem(hDlg, PB_TWO), 0, rcButton.left, rcButton.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
ShowWindow(GetDlgItem(hDlg, PB_TWO), SW_SHOW);
```

have to current replace rcButton.left and rcButton.top with p.x and a hard value for rcButton.top to get the button to position on the dialog screen.

This returns an error in SetWindowPos where parameter 3 cannot convert a LONG * into an INT.

Comment: Make sure `p.x = 0; p.y = 0;` before calling `ClientToScreen`. Also hide `PB_ONE`. You said you already changed `&rcButton.left` to `rcButton.left`?

Comment: Yes I changed them.  However, these coordinates are always off the screen.  I have to use p.x instead of rcButton.left to actually get the correct button positions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetWindowRect` gives the rectangle in screen coordinates. You can convert this to client coordinates using `ScreenToClient(HWND hWnd, LPPOINT lpPoint)`.

---

*Edit:*

```
RECT rcButton;
HWND hbutton1 = GetDlgItem(hDlg, PB_ONE);
HWND hbutton2 = GetDlgItem(hDlg, PB_TWO);

//if(!hbutton1 || !hbutton2) {error...}

GetWindowRect(hbutton1, &rcButton);

//Test
char buf[50];
sprintf(buf, "%d %d", rcButton.left, rcButton.top);
MessageBoxA(0, buf, "screen coord", 0);

//Note, this will only convert the top-left corner, not right-bottom corner
//but that's okay because we only want top-left corner in this case
ScreenToClient(hDlg, (POINT*)&rcButton);

//Test
sprintf(buf, "%d %d", rcButton.left, rcButton.top);
MessageBoxA(0, buf, "client coord", 0);

ShowWindow(hbutton1, SW_HIDE);
SetWindowPos(hbutton2, 0, rcButton.left, rcButton.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

---

A slightly simpler way is to use `ClientToScreen(HWND hWnd, LPPOINT lpPoint)` as follows:

```
RECT rcButton;
GetWindowRect(GetDlgItem(hDlg, PB_ONE), &rcButton);

POINT p{ 0 };
ClientToScreen(hDlg, &p);
//p is now (0,0) of parent window in screen coordinates
OffsetRect(&rcButton, -p.x, -p.y);
```

`rcButton` is now the coordinates relative to top-left of parent window. You can use that in `SetWindowPos`.

Comment: This is giving me an error with the SetWindowPos call -  Param 3 cannot set a LONG* to a INT

Comment: My fault - I was using & - code works fine.  The button isn't on the screen though, I'm assuming its at pos 0,0 ?

Comment: Try the *Edit* section. You should use debug break points or `OutputDebugString` to see what values you are getting. If possible, move the dialog towards the top-left of desktop screen, so that screen and client coordinates are roughly the same (that's useful for testing only).

Comment: Try to copy/paste the code in "Edit" section, exactly as is. I added some `MessageBox` to examine the values, but you can use debug break points or OutputDebugString to see these values.